# Execute statement between 2 elif blocks

Tags: python, optimization, control-flow

Is there any way to execute statements between the (false) evaluation of 1 elif block and the evaluation of the next in Python 3.x?
I wish to optimise my program by only running the function "word_in_special_list" should the first 2 statements of an if block evaluate as false.
Ideally the program would look something like this:

```
for word in lis:          
    #Finds word in list
    if word_in_first_list(word):
        score += 1

    elif word_in_second_list(word):
        score -= 1

    #Since the first 2 evaluations return false, the following statement is now run
    a, b = word_in_special_list(word)
    #This returns a Boolean value, and an associated score if it's in the special list
    #It is executed only if the word isn't in the other 2 lists, 
    #and executed before the next elif

    elif a:
        score += b  #Add b to the running score

    else:
        ...other things...
    #end if
#end for
```

Of course, putting a tuple in a elif evaluation returns an error. I also can't restructure my if statement because it is more likely that the word will be in the first or second list, and so this structure saves time. So is there any way to run a code block in between 2 elif evaluations?

Comment: If you just turn `elif a:` to `if a:`, will it not do what you've written in the comments?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that would only succeed in the function being run every iteration regardless of how the first two conditions evaluate.

Comment: No, there is no way to do exactly what you are stating.

Cory's solution comes (so far) to closest and I would recommend it over elif word_in_special_list(word)[0]: clause for readability and to avoid the redundant function call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to make an `else` case then nest within that

```
for word in lis:          
    if word_in_first_list(word):
        score += 1 
    elif word_in_second_list(word):
        score -= 1
    else:
        a, b = word_in_special_list(word)
        if a:
            score += b  #Add b to the running score
        else:
            ...other things...
```

Comment: It looks good, but what I'm asking is if there's any way to do what I suggested above.

Comment: @David.  This has the logic you want, though, doesn't it?  `word_in_special_list` only runs if it's not in the first or second list.  Note how the nesting is different from your question.  `if a:` is inside the `else` clause of the outer `if/elif/else` chain.

Comment: @David use a debugger to step through your code and see how it is getting evaluated (or use print statements). Learning to use the debugger is much better

Answer (score 0):

You could put in `continue` statements.

```
for word in lis:          
    #Finds word in list
    if word_in_first_list(word):
        score += 1
        continue

    if word_in_second_list(word):
        score -= 1
        continue

    a, b = word_in_special_list(word)

    if a:
        score += b  #Add b to the running score

    else:
        ...other things...
```

I think this has the effect you're trying to achieve.  Incidentally, I don't see why you need the function `word_in_first_list`.  What's wrong with `if word in first_list`?